# Comma Separate String using handlebars.js

Tags: handlebars.js

These days working i am working with handlerbars.js and it seems pretty interesting. In there i need a small help from you guys.

i have a following json input

```
"ALERTS": [
    {
        "alert_description": "ALCOHOL",
    },
    {
        "alert_description": "DIAGNOSIS",
    }
]
```

and i need to write a template to create following comma separated string.

```
ALCOHOL, DIAGNOSIS
```

i was able to print these values using line by line using following template.

```
<div>
   <div>
{{#each this}}
    <span>{{alert_description}}</span>
{{/each}}
</div>
</div>
```

can you guys please help me to solve this issue? appreciate your help

Thanks
Keth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this without writing a helper by using {{#each}} and testing the implicit @index variable:

```
{{#each this}}
    {{#if @index}}, {{/if}}
    <span>{{alert_description}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

You can also test @first and @last (see [handlebarsjs docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html)).

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of scenario, I will create a helper.

Here is my implementation

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('commalist', function(items, options) {
  var out = '';

  for(var i=0, l=items.length; i<l; i++) {
    out = out + options.fn(items[i]) + (i!==(l-1) ? ",":"");
  }
  return out;
});
```

and the template

```
<div>
   <div>
    {{#commalist this}}
       <span>{{alert_description}}</span>
    {{/commalist}}
   </div>
</div>
```

In fact, the helper is here only for comma. You can still put html inside the helper (span, div, ...)